# How do I run another file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory

So I know how to write in a file or read a file but how do I RUN another file?

for example in a file I have this:
`a = 1`
`print(a)`

How do I run this using another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_path = "<path_to_your_python_file>"
```

using `subprocess` standard lib

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python3", file_path])
```

or using `os` standard lib

```
import os
os.system(f"python3 {file_path}")
```

or extract `python code` from the file and run it inside your script:

```
with open(file_path, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as another_file:
  python_code = another_file.read()

# running the code inside the file
exec(python_code)
```

`exec` is a function that runs python strings exactly how `python interpreter` runs `python files`.

**IN ADDITION**

if you want to see the output of the python file:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(
  ["python3", file_path], 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
err, output = p.communicate()
print(err)
print(output)
```

**EXTRA**

for people who are using `python2`:

```
execfile(file_path)
```

[exec_file documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/execfile.html)

Comment: In python 2 you can also use `execfile`

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken python interpreter does not compile files. It is an interpreter after all.